# Causal modelling: specifying model additively or hierarchically?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, causality, hierarchical-bayesian

Let's assume we would like to examine **regional disparities** in income. We are **NOT interested in country-wide effects**. A DAG tells us to adjust for age and education. DAGs do not tell anything about additive or hierarchical model specification. Should we specify region additively or hierarchically?

```
income ~ age + education + region
```

or

```
income ~ age + education + (1 | region)
```

Isn't it so that **regional-level** effects would be very similar with both models? What would be your considerations in this case?